# MAGENTO 2 System error after first install

Tags: magento2, error, indexer

It is my first time that I tried to install magento and I followed the tutorial at the following link:

https://medium.com/@purvirawal.work/magento-2-installation-on-mac-os-f78981ecea92

However, I have a **system ERROR** on the top saying "**One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running.**".

I am using MAMP on OSX, any idea how I could resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

run below command from magento root directory.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: After i did what you said i got the following error:                                                     
  [Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                       
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  
                                                    




                                                    
  [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  
                                                    


indexer:reindex [index1] ... [indexN]